# Ao entrar no ADMIN do WP aparece somente o Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Ao fazer login no wordpress todas as configurações aparecem e 2 segundos depois  fica somente o menu. A tela fica branca e não consigo acessar nada.

Já tentei pelo celular e pelo computador e não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um vídeo para mostrar o erro de fato: https://youtu.be/2sJRyiO-Uzg

Comment: Ja tentou dar um inspecionar elemento e ver se não tem algo ocultando eles com css?

Comment: Alguns itens no menu funcionam.. Warning! WP Super Cache caching was broken but has been fixed! The script advanced-cache.php could not load wp-cache-phase1.php.

Comment: Desativa o wp super cache para ver

Comment: Não aparecem nenhum css ocultando no inspect.

Comment: Vou tentar renomear o plugin via FTP pois pelo admin não está dando realmente.

Comment: Pode parecer besta, mas tenta instalar outra versao do WP ... pode ser alguma incompatibilidade com algum plugin ativo. 

Em outro navegador acontece isso ? Desculpa não consigo ver o video(im at the work )

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro em todos os navegadores! Não consigo atualizar o wp pois não consigo acessar o menu de atualização ali no admin.

Comment: Vou fazer via FTP

Comment: Resolvido. Renomei o Plugin WP Total Cache e voltou ao normal. Obrigado!